# Accessing HTTP content from an HTTPS server || HTTP request blocked

Tags: django, http, https, request, devops

My  Django application currently runs on **HTTPS** in the server. Recently i added a new functionality for which it has access another link to get **JSON object** which is **HTTP** link.

Its working fine in the localhost but when I deploy it in the server, it is showing the following error.

**`Site was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource http link.  This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`**

Can someone please suggest a workaround to bypass this so that the new functionality runs smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes from the browser, so there is not match you can do on the server side.

Easiest thing would be to enable https to those external resources if you have control over that.

Next workaround would be to add a proxy for your http resources and make this proxy https. In example, you could add a simple nginx server with proxy_pass to your http server and add https on that proxy'ing nginx.

Note, that if this JSON you are talking about contains anything sensitive, security-wise you really should serve it via https and not via proxy-workaround I described above. If nothing sensitive is served, workaround might be ok.

Since you have control over your http server, just allow ssl proxy on the nginx, with configuration that may look something like that:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name my.host.name;
  ssl_certificate       /path/to/cert;
  ssl_certificate_key   /path/to/key;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
  }
}
```

Note, if you're using something like AWS / GCP / Azure - you can do it on the load balancer side instead of nginx.
Otherwise, you can use letsencrypt to get the actual certificate and do some auto-configuration of nginx for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. data is not sensitive. Regarding workaround, you want me to add nginx_reverse_proxy to the server which is http?

Comment: You can spin a brand new server (with any domain name) and point proxy_pass to your http one - that is if you don't have control over existing server. Or if you have control over http server, you can do it directly on that server.

Comment: I have control over http server. proxy_pass and nginx_reverse_proxy are same?

Comment: Reverse proxy is a name for the process of what is actually happening. While proxy_pass is a specific configuration instruction for nginx. I updated the answer to include sample configuration and few more details.